# Dynamically push an element to the end of an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Is there a way to dinamycally push an element to the end of an array?
Similar to Javascript `array.push` in `VBA`?

I need to push an element to the end of an array but I don't know its size.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
Dim similarValues() As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For j = 1 To 10
    if "condition" then
    ReDim Preserve similarValues("lenght of the array")
    similarValues("lenght of the array") = j
    End if
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know of anything to do that in one step but you can find the lower and upper bounds of your array with `lbound` and `ubound` which can get you the size.

Comment: @Sobigen thanks, but if the array is empty (on the 1st round of the loop) than UBound doesn't work, does it?

Comment: you can test with `IsEmpty`. I believe it works with Arrays.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I think you need IsArray

Comment: @Jzz - `IsArray` only tests if it is an Array, which will return true as long as it declared. I did test `IsEmpty` and it does not work either. Meaning it returns False whether array is populated or dimensioned or not.

Comment: I tested and got False for `IsEmpty()` on an uninitialized array.  I got True from `IsArray()` on an uninitialized array.  Which I don't think is what you want in this case.  I've haven't found a simple one line function to check an array.  I have my own function with error handling that I've used in the past.  `Ubound` on an uninitialized array will raise an error.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Of course it was an array already. You could use a Variant instead of an uninitialized array. Then you could test with IsArray(). I think that would work. EDIT: tested, but no, it does not.

Comment: Have you considered using a collection instead? That does exactly what you want. Furthermore, collections are much faster in access, in case you are using large numbers.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array starts at 1 based on this loop, doing this the way you have set up would be:

```
For j = 1 To 10
    if "condition" then
    ReDim Preserve similarValues(1 To j) 'reevaluates array from 1 to ubound + 1
    similarValues(j) = 'whatever
    End if
Next j
```

However, this probably won't work since you are looping j, this would leave empty array values where your if condition is not met.  I would:

```
Dim i As integer
i = 1
For j = 1 To 10
    if "condition" then
        ReDim Preserve similarValues(1 To i) 'reevaluates array from 1 to i
        similarValues(i) = 'whatever
        i = i + 1 'i is only increased when the if condition is met
    End if
Next j
```

This should keep your array size and the number of items inside it consistent

EDIT:  Sorry I didn't see that this isn't an array that you're creating but one that already exists.  You can use LBound and UBound() to find size if it is initialized, and if it is uninitialized, you can use an error handler to initialize it:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

ErrHandler:
    ReDim Preserve similarValues(1 To 1)
    'Statement to navigate back to loop
```

In this case you could use:

```
ComeBack:
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
For j = 1 To 10
    if "condition" then
    ReDim Preserve similarValues(1 To UBound(similarValues) + 1) 'reevaluates array from 1 to j
    similarValues(UBound(similarValues)) = 'whatever
    End if
Next j

ErrHandler:
    ReDim Preserve similarValues(1 To 1)
    GoTo ComeBack
```

And alternatively, if you know it is uninitialized to begin with, you can ReDim from 1 to 1 before the loop to make sure it is initialized

Comment: thanks, I had that kind of solution in my mind also, but was wondering if there was a more direct way of doing it (without requiring the extra i variable).

Comment: @NunoNogueira  I added some more edits.  Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: I'm testing it right now, I think it'll work. The thing is I have 12 arrays for which I need to push elements to the end and it's not very practical to do it with this kind of solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it works, because on the 1st round of the loop, it goes to the error handler but the loop stops. I guess it would be better to declare the array with something in it on the beggining of the code?

Comment: @NunoNogueira, Sorry, I didn't code that part out, I just put in a comment at the end of the ErrHandler... You can use a GoTo statement to go back to before the loop.  You would have to put in a line number, like '1' before the loop and then say GoTo 1 (line number does not actually have to match the line number in the program.  I will edit this in

Comment: @NunoNogueira  Let me know if it still isn't working.  You will have to watch different types of errors with this method and may need to specify in the handler that this should only be used when a specific error occurs.  It may be easier to just initialize the array from the start and tweak the program from there

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do now: initialize the array from the start.